# How to check authorization for a particular account in EOS smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts, eosio.cdt, authorization

I want to write an **EOS** smart contract to manage users data. I need that only some admin account will able to add, update and delete users and the particular user can only update data. Can I check specific account authorization in a smart contract? And for update, can I check authorization of account either it should be admin or user? I am planning to set the primary key as each user account name.
In this,

```
void insert(name user, std::string first_name, std::string last_name, std::string street, std::string city, std::string state) {
  require_auth( user );
}
```

It is checking authorization of a particular user, but I need it for an admin account who is going to do all transactions. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for an iterator with given key from multi_index first.

- iterator found: already created item, require_auth(user)
- iterator not found: not created item, require_auth(admin)

Permission check can be done in any step of your method. (Even you call require_auth() at the last time of your method, its failure reverts all changes made during that transaction)

--

You can separate insert/update or make them into one method like upsert.

```
void insert(name user, std::string first_name, ...) {
  require_auth("varshadmin"_n); // specific admin account name
  ...
}

void update(name user, ...) {
  check(has_auth(user) || has_auth("varshadmin"_n), "missing required authorization");
  ...
}

void upsert(name user, ...) {
  addressbook addr(_self, _self.value);
  auto itr = addr.find(user);
  if (itr == addr.end()) {
    // case 1: create new item
    require_auth("varshadmin"_n);
    addr.emplace(...);
  } else {
    // case 2: update existing utem
    check(has_auth(user) || has_auth("varshadmin"_n), "missing required authorization");
    addr.modify(itr, ...);
  }
}
```

Comment: require_auth(admin) : Can I pass directly the name of admin account in smart contract code like require_auth(member) whereas member is an account name.

Comment: Means checking the specific account authorization.

Comment: Why not? I added an example to original answer.

Comment: Hey thanx a lot for the answer.

Comment: Does it compulsory to pass "user" i.e user account name while inserting or updating his/her data? Especially if we need to check users authorization.

Comment: I can't get your scenario well. Without "user", where do you get the account name of required authorization? How do you find multi_index item without "user" name?

Comment: EOSIO transaction can have multiple authorization like [alice@active, bob@active] in one action, so "user" name is usually passed as argument. It is difficult to determine what user name should be used without explicit argument.

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain well.  For now, I am using "user" as a primary key of the current User smart contract. But in future may be admin will only maintain users data without their account names. This means he will not have accounts of users. And all transactions will be signed by him. In that case, how this primary key "user" will work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108281/discussion-between-varsh-and-conr2d).